# Restkit 0.23.1 while adding iCloud-Enabled Persistent Store

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, icloud

Has anyone had any success using RestKit with a persistent store that is flagged with iCloud-enable syncing? (ubiquity container)

I've added `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"iCloudStore"` to the list of options when adding the persistent store to the `RKManagedObjectStore`. When executing, I never get the message `Using location storage: 0` to indicate the link to iCloud.

Is my setup incorrect?

```
// Managed Object Model setup
    modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyModel"
                                  withExtension:@"momd"];
    model = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];

    // RestKit Managed Object Store
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    store = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

    // RestKit Persistent Store setup
    path = [DocumentsDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyData.sqlite"];
    options = @{
                NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"iCloudStore"
                };

//Add persistent store
[store addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path
                   fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                        withConfiguration:nil
                                  options:options
                                    error:&error];
```

I seemed to trace the issue to the swapping of persistent stores within RestKit when dealing with database seeding. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something stupid before I opened an issue with RestKit.

Comment: You should get a better answer with an issue

Comment: I was going to post an issue, but wanted to make sure I wasn't out to lunch, before I did it.